# vb.NET "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Tags: vb.net

I'm receiving the following error in VB.Net.

"Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

```
Try

    Dim myurl As String
    myurl = "http://example.com/page.php?user=" & uzjer
    WebBrowser1.Url = New Uri(myurl)

    For Each ele As HtmlElement In WebBrowser1.Document.Links
        Dim username As String
        username = ele.GetAttribute("name")

        MsgBox(username)

    Next
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.Message)
End Try
```

Comment: **Where** do you get the error? What's the stack trace?

Comment: Remove the Try-Catch and see where the error occurs.

Comment: If I will remove Try-Catch I will get the same error

Comment: Yes, but on which line? Have you run it in debug?

Comment: What is uzjer? and what if the GetAttribute call doesnt find an attribute called name? That'll leave you an object reference error. Try    'Dim username as String = String.Empty' Short of that we'll need more info!

Comment: **Do not separate declaration and initialisation!** Initialise variables directly in the declaration, not afterwards. This makes the code significantly shorter and ensures that variables always have their desired value rather than remaining accidentally uninitialised.

Answer (score 0):

With the information you provided here are the possible causes

- `uzjer` could be `null`
- `GetAttribute("name")` returns `null` and then you try to display it in a MessageBox

Try to assign a value to `username` before using `GetAttribute("name")` to make sure it's not null.

If you want a more specific answer, please give me the line where you get the error.

Answer (score 0):

I see several problems here.

First up is that you never navigate to your URL. Assigning to the WebBrowser Url property is not what you want to do. The result is that when you check the links, the elements have no "name" property. This means you are returning a null reference to the username field, and causing the NullReferenceException when you pass that null variable to MsgBox(). Use the WebBrowser's [.Navigate()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/40x214wa.aspx) function.

Next, you are looping through all the links in the documents. Any of those links that don't have a name property will cause the same problem as your navigate issue. You should be looking for the one username link.

Comment: The error are showing in this line: 
For Each ele As HtmlElement In WebBrowser1.Document.Links

If I do like this, everything works
MsgBox("1")
For Each ele As HtmlElement In WebBrowser1.Document.Links

Comment: @chizijs that's because you have no Document. WebBrowser1 nas not finished navigating to the page, so it's .Document property is `Nothing`. Trying to reference the `.Links` property of the Nothing reference is what throws the exception. You have to call WebBrowser1.Navigate(), and then you have to wait for it to finish.